# OFbiz configuration on production site

Tags: http-status-code-404, ofbiz

I'm new to OFBiz and having trouble making it work on production. I'd appreciate it very much if you could help me to narrow down or even better solve the problem :-)

1. I was able to able to run OFbiz successfully at localhost and access data that came with the project (ex:  https://localhost:8443/webtools/control/entitymaint)
2. I went through the steps setting up SSL for the project on production site on my Windows Server (I was able to access https://www.mywebsitedomain.com)
3. I created a folder called ROOT and put the OFBiz folder(same folder on my localhost) in the ROOT folder
4. I also have set up an SSL Certificate, then added the following to server.xml under Tomcat 9.

   (Connector port="8443" maxThreads="150"
   scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
   keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\apache-ofbiz-17.12.03\keystore.jks" keystorePass="Password"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS")
   (/Connector)
5. When running https://www.mywebsitedomain/webtools/control/entitymaint(same URL except for localhost), I got the message.

"404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

**Edit: Add some additional information**

6. I found the following information on the OFBiz Production SetUP page:

"Configure the ofbiz-containers.xml file to point to your new keystore and password:

If using Tomcat (Catalina), which is the default, find the "catalina-container" -> "https-connector" -> "keystoreFile" and "keystorePass" properties and set them."

I go to apache-ofbiz-17.12.03\framework\base\config\ofbiz-containers.xml
All the entries I have are below. I don't know where I can add "keystoreFile" and "keystorePass" properties

```
<ofbiz-containers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/ofbiz-containers.xsd">

<!-- load the ofbiz component container (always first) -->
<container name="component-container" loaders="main,rmi,load-data,test" class="org.apache.ofbiz.base.container.ComponentContainer"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Jessie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found, OFBiz uses an embedded Tomcat (9.0.31). So server.xml is of no help. This wiki page needed update, done. The file you are looking for is framework\catalina\ofbiz-component.xml.

But I'm not sure you are going the right way doing this. Most of the time, it's easier to use Apache HTTPD, even on Windows. You may refer to https://s.apache.org/vmemj. Also for certificates [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is what we use for our demos. It's free and, apart the renewal every 3 months, it's great. With [their cerbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/windows-other.html) that's even not a big deal.

By and large, you should better ask questions in the OFBiz user Mailing List.You need to subscribe, please see https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

HTH

Comment: Hi JacquesLeRoux, Thanks a lot for providing me the information. I'll check into them and post questions in the OFBiz user Mailing List in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In point 4 you speak about the following, but I see nothing, do I miss something?

Comment: Hi JacquesLeRoux, First, thank you very much for answering my question. I like the program very much. I played around the project on my localhost and would love to make it work on my domain. I added the code for #4 (it was there, but for some reason the page didn't like <> although I tried to entered them as Code, anyway, I changed it to (). On my domain server, I have them as <>. Also, While I was waiting for some help. I searched more online about OFBiz and found some additional information. I added my additional found in my original post as well

Answer (score 0):

You could also ditch OFBiz and migrate to the awesome Scipio ERP (based on the same foundation): [www.scipioerp.com](http://www.scipioerp.com)

We have a documentation on exactly your question right here: https://www.scipioerp.com/community/developer/installation-configuration/clustering/webserver-configuration/